# Не работает jQuery при подключение к Wordpress, пробовал разные варианты подключения, ничего не работает

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Вот код

```
<?php
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'siteen_scripts');

    function siteen_scripts(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'siteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'siteen-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', array(), null, true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'siteen-scripts-min', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'siteen-scripts-preloader', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/preloader.js', array(), null, true);
    }

    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть проблема с jQuery, не могу подключить один файл, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: "Не работает" - худшее описание из возможных. Приведите полное описание ошибок, которые вы видите и отличие реального поведение от желаемого.

Comment: Тема основная или дочерняя?

Answer (score 0):

Надо указывать зависимость скриптов от jQuery. А сам jQuery запускать не нужно, его запустит ядро.

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'siteen_scripts' );

function siteen_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'siteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'siteen-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js', [ 'jquery' ], null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'siteen-scripts-preloader', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/preloader.js', [ 'jquery' ], null, true );
}

add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
```

Возможно, это не единственные ошибки.